# If statement is being ignored when checking for index[0] of an array in C

Tags: c, string, function, if-statement

I'm trying to check if the index of a equals to + - / or *
However when I run my program it seems to ignore my if statement.

How can I run the if statement when index of array a = to the above mentioned operators?

```
int main()
{
    double result = 0;
    char a[25] ;
    char b[25] ;

    char hold = a[0];
    while (a != 'quit')
    {

        printf("Calculate number: ");

        fgets(a, 25, stdin);
        x = a;

        if (hold == "+" || hold == '-' || hold == '/' || hold == '*') {//this is getting ignored


            sprintf_s(b, 25, "%lf", result);
            strcat_s(b, 25, a);
            x = b;
            printf("this is error");
        }
    
        result = parsesum();
        printf("result is:%lf \n", result);

    }
}
```

Comment: To begin with, `while (a != 'quit')` is not valid in multiple ways. You can't compare strings with `!=` (except in very specific cases), and `'quit'` is not a valid string.

Comment: You want to use `a`, so how about using `a`? : `if (a[0] == '+' || a[0] == '-' || a[0] == '/' || a[0] == '*')`

Comment: In fact, `x` is also undefined (as is `parsesum()`). Maybe you should post a little more.

Comment: You also attempt to use the contents of `a` (once you fix the comparison) before`a` is initialized. The array `a` will start out with *indeterminate* contents, and using it can lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You never assign anything (valid) to `hold`. You can't just set it equal to an array element and then expect it to 'follow' changes in that array.

Comment: `char hold = a[0];` invokes *Undefined Behavior* as it accesses the value of an object with automatic storage duration while the value is indeterminate. `a` has not been initialized at that point.

Comment: Raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum and change your source until no more warnings or errors are output. Most of your problems come from ignoring warnings.